# Python GUI - Insert text to text box

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I just got into Python GUIs and I am testing different things, since that seems to help me learn easier (trial and error).  One thing I am trying is inserting a message from a different class.  I can honestly say, I don't know what I would use this for, but I am just trying it for the sake of trying.

```
# Hello World
# Displays "Hello World!" in a text box.

from tkinter import *

class myClass(object):
    def myMethod():
        print("Hello World!")

class Application(Frame):
    """ GUI application which can reveal the secret of longevity. """
    def __init__ (self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        # Create a text box
        self.txtBox = Text(self, width = 300, height = 300, wrap = WORD)
        self.txtBox.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

        # display message
        message = myClass.myMethod
        self.txtBox.insert(0.0, message)

# main
root = Tk()
root.title("My Title")
root.geometry("500x500")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run the .py file I get the GUI and then a box that says `<function myClass.myMethod at 0x0000000002A1C6A8>` - If I am not mistaken this means that is where myMethod is stored in memory.

So I used `message = myClass.myMethod()` thinking that this would output *"Hello World!"* - Instead I get an error.  At first it was something along the lines of object.**init** doesn't take parameters or something like that (apologies because I wasn't able to recreate the error) - now I am getting `tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "43128536.43105360 insert index chars ?tagList chars tagList...?`

Is this possible to have the "Hello World!" from another class, print in a GUI text box?

Also, while I was looking over the code, I am curious.  What is the purpose of `app = Application(root)`?  When I don't have it there, I get a blank GUI.  However, I don't see that it actually calls app to do anything other than setting it equal to `Application(root)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding function itself to textbox. Call the function and use the return value of it.

```
    message = myClass.myMethod()
    self.txtBox.insert(1.0, message)
```

`myClass` need a modification. return the string instead of print it.

```
class myClass(object):
    def myMethod():
        return "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!  May I ask, why does `return` work in this case and not `print`?  I still get confused as to when I should use them.

Comment: @mccdlibby, `print` does not return. It just print to terminal.

Comment: 0.0 is an invalid index. Text widget lines are numbered from 1, not zero.